# Transit in Heathrow

Tags: uk, lhr, stopovers

I am from Saudi Arabia travelling to the USA with a valid visa.
Can I stay overnight in London?
Do I have to take my checked luggage or can it be left at the airport for the next days flight?

Comment: It doesn’t seem like the linked duplicate addresses these questions.

Comment: @ZachLipton If OP uses the visa tool linked by the other answer, they will be told that they are eligible for transit without visa since they are traveling to the US. This conclusively answers the transit question.

Comment: @MJeffryes: But the part that asks (IIUC) if he can check is baggage through for an overnight layover is not answered there.

Comment: That's one of the reasons not to ask many questions in one post. The questions should be edited and after that it could be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

The duplicate target suggested in comments should give you the answer you need for the visa part.

As for not collecting your checked baggage, you will need to ask the airline if they will agree to check your baggage through to the US destination even across an overnight layover in London. *Usually* airlines don't do that, but there might be a chance if it's a tight late-night-to-early-morning connection. Call the airline and ask them. Or ask nicely when you check in and be prepared for either outcome.